# infinite gulp watch loop

Tags: javascript, gulp

Trying to figure out my gulpfile.js (newbie)

Here's the gulpfile.js, once i run gulp it just keeps running. There's no bundle command which i've read in some other posts. I just want it obviously to take notice to any changes and run once until the next change.

```
/* Required */
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
    rename = require('gulp-rename');


/* Scripts Task */
gulp.task('scripts', function(){
    gulp.src(['app/js/**/*.js', '!app/js/**/*/min.js'])
    .pipe(rename({suffix:'.min'}))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js'));
});

/* Watch Task */
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
});

/* Default Task */
gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'watch']);
```

Comment: minor detail but you probably wanted `uglify = require('gulp-uglify');` to end with a comma instead of a semicolon.

Comment: Ah thank you, but this does not solve this annoying repetition! This seems fun, but i'm getting stuck here

Comment: `'!app/js/**/*/min.js']` should this be `'!app/js/**/*min.js']`?

Comment: Timolawl, thank you my friend!

Comment: you're welcome! I added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 3):

`'!app/js/**/*/min.js'` should be `'!app/js/**/*min.js'`.

As the second one *does not* match any files ending in `min.js` in all sub-directories of `app/js`.